# How to employ an error alert system in a deployed Django Site

Tags: django

I am deploying my django site soon!! In `debug=True` mode, there is an error page that comes up when there is some bug in the code.

When in `debug=False` mode, after I deploy, I want to set up something so that I am alerted whenever anyone on the prod site reaches this page. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This setup would send an email after someone make a request. Here is the documention on sending emails through Django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/

```
   def home_page(request):

       send_mail(
         'Site Visitor',
         'someone visted the site.',
         'from@example.com',
         ['to@example.com'],
         fail_silently=False,
       )
    
       return render(request, 'template')
```

For an "error alert system," you can look into Sentry. https://sentry.io/for/django/